# How to add text on box decoration in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a box decoration on which I need to add a text as shown in below image.
"Hello, username"

I did multiple attempts using Stack and Positioned, however somehow my image gets disappear. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please advise.

Now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqwSS.png)

Expected:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZyBp.png)

My widget looks like this,

```
class dashboardHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const dashboardHeader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
            Color(0xff47BA79),
            Color(0xff47BA79),
            Color(0xff3E4982)
          ]),
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: AssetImage("assets/tennis.png"),
            colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.19), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(16))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be adding the `Text` as the child of the `Container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Values according to your requirements

```
Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0,horizontal: 20.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("asset/img.png",),fit: BoxFit.fill,),
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        RichText(text: TextSpan(
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(text: "Hello\n",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            TextSpan(text: "Kalpesh\n",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
          ]
        ))
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
          Color(0xff47BA79),
          Color(0xff47BA79),
          Color(0xff3E4982)
        ]),
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: AssetImage("assets/tennis.png"),
          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.19), BlendMode.dstATop),
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(16))),
    child: //PUT HERE YOUR WIDGET,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. Used Srack Widget. just change your image with my image.

```
Center(
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xff3e4982),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: NetworkImage(
                "https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png"),
            colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.19), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Hello',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Kalpesh',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Your Result screen-> [image]